# Can Athasian psionicist/druids evolve into "advanced beings" like the other caster classes?

Tags: druid, psionics, adnd-2e, epic-tier, dark-sun

In Athas, there are options for high level Psionicist / Clerics or Psionicist / (Defilers | Preservers) to become advanced beings.

Is there such an advancement path for high level Psionicist / Druids?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, according to the supplement *Earth, Air, Fire and Water* they can turn into spirits of the land.

Comment: Note: The spirits of the land transformation (melding with, not actually *becoming*, a spirit of the land) is woefully underspecified. It's basically just a table of XP values, typo-ed natural AC values (it looks like it's supposed to be AC 0 at level 21, dropping to -5 by level 30, but half the values omit the negative sign, so as written, you sometimes jump from AC -2 to AC 3, or from AC 4 to -4, across a single level divide), and bonus hit dice. You need Dragon Kings to figure out what abilities Druids (advanced being or otherwise) get from 21 to 30 beyond AC and hit dice.